# Can't authenticate mobile client with node.js (using passport.js)

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to build some CRUD application with node.js as a back-end API (express)
and web-app (backbone) and mobile client (native android) as front-ends.(I'm node.js beginner)

My server solution is based on the following great tutorial ['easy-node-authentication'](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-google).

In my android app I have managed to get the user Google-Token after I completed the authentication step with Google Plus SDK.(mobile to google-plus directly request).

I'm trying to understand and find right and elegant way to re-use a given google-token and authenticate again my android user through Google-Plus account to ensure the mobile client holds real token, then add a new entry (id, token, email, name) to my users table DB within my node back-end.

The question is: what should be my next step in case I want to keep my back-end without changes? should I send a GET request with the token as a cookie to /auth/google? maybe to /auth/google/callback? another URL? Does this make sense at all?

Please note: I'm aware to the fact the mentioned above 'easy-node-auth' solution is based on sessions and cookies. having said that, i'm still trying to understand if there is a convenient way to integrate both (android and node) as it works good for my web-app and node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I had the same issue with facebook authentication. The easiest would be to only use the SIGNUP solution described in http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-google but keep the google auth LOGIN on the client side.
You authentication flow must be the same whatever client is using your app. (Browser, Android app, etc..)

So you would need to do the following things (well described here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent):

1. Set up the Google oauth2 login on the browser side (Using the JS SDK) using AJAX. The AJAX response should contain some kind of access token.
2. For every request made from either browser or native client, send the google access token in the Authorization header and check it with nodeJS it against https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo. This will give you the user ID (that you saved in you DB in the signup phase) and check the validity of the token.

So it hurst but you should get rid of the passport module that does the OAuth2 login on google.
It turns out that **step 2** can be done using nodeJS **passport-google-token** module! So this should not be too much work.

Good luck

Comment: Is their anything similar for facebook ?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was stuck at the same problem and your answer has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, this scenario is a bit unique in that you have a client (the android app) that has authenticated itself without the use of your backend application.  But the backend application will be used in subsequent requests and you need to authenticate to that backend app?  If so, then I think as you build this out you'll hit problems with trusting your clients on the backend system, unless it can validate the credentials of the client.  If the backend system could somehow validate this token (from Google) belongs to a certain user, then you could enforce authorization.  Otherwise the backend system would trust all clients that have any "token" no matter the quality (again, please correct me if my understanding is wrong).

It might be better if the backend system could be the one who retrieves this token from Google, which would then make it responsible for authentication.  The client would send the necessary credentials perhaps, which could be sent to create the token.  From then you could easily use cookies to transport the token back and forth within the HTTP requests.

Another option is to build a separate authentication scheme using username/password combination, which is separate from the token that the phone retrieves.  It's just hard to protect the data in the backend (if that is your intention) from any client without validating the client in some way.

Once you decide how to authenticate a user, restricting your APIs based on if a user is authenticated is relatively easy (using something like Passport as you described above).  On the client side, I've found an simple pattern to follow is to redirect users to a login page if any APIs return with a 401 (Unauthorized).

Comment: indeed, i'm trying to find a solution which is based on that mechanism ['easy-node-auth-with-google'](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication). the solution should re-authenticate a given google-token. (revived by my mobile-app) my question is: what is the correct URL to invoke? /auth/google? what parameters should be given to the GET request? thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to re-use the token you acquired in your mobile app (which was an OAuth2 token) in your backend app?  So basically the user grants you permissions on your mobile app and you use the same token to authenticate the user in the backend app?  If so, I'm not sure if that's possible.  If you look at the passport logic in the example you linked, they're using the information in the callback to create a new user, which is then used in subsequent requests.  It doesn't appear that they use the token.  Do you need the user details?

Comment: Yes. Basically I'm looking for any conventional method to authenticate my mobile-app user within my node-server. i'm not worried regarding the user data, since it can be sent manually by the mobile later, any appropriate way to solve this situation will be accepted. (authenticate and create an entry inside my server for an already authenticated via google-plus android user).

Comment: You first mentioned you wanted to re-authenticate given a google token, but are now saying any conventional method is okay?  If any method works, then a username/password would work.  If you want to stick with Google OAuth2, then you can build that solution you linked above.  What I'm trying to say is you might not want to do _both_ -- authenticate on the mobile app *and* authenticate on the backend app.  If you have additional secured data stored in the backend app, you might want to only authenticate there, not the mobile app too.

Comment: I meant any conventional method to re-authenticate my mobile-app via given google-token, since, as you wrote, i have to ensure the mobile-user holds a real google-token.

Comment: There appears to be a method [`userProfile`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/blob/master/lib/passport-google-oauth/oauth2.js#L72) which takes a token and returns (within the callback) the user details.  This function is accessible from the main `GoogleStrategy` object you create for passport configuration.  One option is to send the token to the backend server, and have that server attempt to lookup the user details via that function, which would log the user in.